# Why does my table cell (occasionally) not exhibit 'hover' behaviour until I force element state using Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a table, making use of the following CSS and HTML:

```css
.price { 
    position:relative; 
    display:block; 
    text-align:center; 
}

.detail { 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE; 
    color: #333333; 
    min-width:200px; 
    width:auto; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    left: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;  
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;  
    transition: all .3s ease; 
} 


.price:hover > .detail, .price:hover > .notmuchdata > .detail {
    display:block;
    overflow:auto; 
    left:0px;
    width: 120px;
    height:60px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="price" style="background-color:white;text-decoration: line-through">1.56
            <div class="detail">1.7% @ 1.6</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The desired behaviour of this code is that when the user moves the mouse over the crossed-out numerical value, a div appears with further data.

In most cases, this code seems to function exactly as expected. However, occasionally a user reports that mouseovers are having no effect - the div is not appearing.

It has been difficult to replicate the issue successfully. However, on one occasion I was able to open up Chrome Developer Tools and inspect the cell. On this occasion, I used 'Force Element State' on the cell and set it to ':hover'. Having done so, the hidden div did appear.

So I suppose my general question is, why might the :hover pseudo-class not work (but only occasionally)? And yet demonstrate the expected behaviour when using the Dev Tools to force the hover state?

**EDIT 1**
In trying to make the problem as concise and clear as possible, I did not include the additional detail that the page makes use of AJAX requests in another area of the page. These have occasionally not returned the pure JSON they were intended to, causing a javascript error to appear on the console.

Comment: As with any bugs that only show themselves occasionally and (sometimes) go away when you open the dev-tools, it's going to be a hell of a pain to debug. There have been historical bugs with <tr> hovers, but the last I recall browsers fixed those years ago.

Comment: I agree with @Nit thats going to be a tough one too debug since it only shows up occasionally. Did you know which browsers the were being used when the issue happened? It may be a browser related issue. I would try taking wrapping the 1.56 in its own DIV. http://jsfiddle.net/0mdonxuq/

Comment: Why are you setting the `TD` to `position:relative` and `display:block`? These seem like candidates for causing issues.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, I am setting the td to `position:relative` so that when I set `left:0px` for the accompanying div, this `0px` is measured from the table cell and not the page's overall html tag. So, the div will appear right next to the cell, and not right next to the far left hand side of the page. See the w3schools tutorial on CSS positioning ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)):  "An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is <html>".

Comment: @crazymatt The browser being used was Google Chrome. The problem also seemed to appear on other browsers e.g. Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera.

Comment: Thanks for  your input @Nit, yes, I did recall seeing some mentions of problems with tr hovers, but as you rightly mentioned, these seemed to have happened a number of years ago.

Comment: @KevinBoucher `display:block` does indeed seem to be redundant. Have removed. Must have crept in during various experiments with trying to get the CSS to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My Original Question

In my original question above, I tried to simplify the details of the issue as much as possible, in the interests of clarity.

### More Details

However, I have now added the fact that AJAX is made use of elsewhere in the page.

I think this may be relevant because of the 'occasional' nature of the problem...

The AJAX request is used to call a PHP page that is meant to send back pure JSON, which is then processed in order to display a graph on the page.

Usually this worked as normal, but occasionally there was an error on this php page, and instead of sending back pure JSON, the AJAX request sent a string that included a warning message. This resulted in an error message appearing in the 'JavaScript Console' part of Chrome Developer Tools (and of course the graph not displaying as it should).

I had discounted this behaviour as not being relevant to my issue above, because when I noticed it happening, the hovers seemed to be working normally. That is, it only seemed to be affecting the graphs.

However, as I have said, the 'occasional' nature of this problem makes me wonder if there is in some way a connection.

### The Cause?

My theory is that when problems were encountered in the JavaScript code (due to the AJAX request sometimes not returning pure JSON), this in turn caused problems in executing the CSS hover behaviour that should have been activated when the mouse was over the cell.

### Specific Actions Taken

So the action I have taken is the following:

1. I have added `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` to the beginning of the php file that provides the response to the AJAX request. This should hopefully ensure that the file only ever sends back the pure JSON that my page expects.
2. In the interests of completeness, I feel I should also mention that I have set the `z-index` of the div when in hover 'mode' to a large number (100), although I am doubtful that this should make a difference.

### Did It Fix the Problem?

As noted above, the 'hard to reproduce' nature of this problem makes it hard to know whether this action has succeeded, but it has been a few days now and the problem has not been reported again.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say as I cannot reproduce it, but I would start by eliminating all non-essential CSS declarations (and making a class for the strikethrough -- though it's probably not the issue):

```
.price { 
    text-align: center; 
}

.strike {
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.detail { 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE; 
    color: #333333; 
    min-width: 200px; /* <-- why min-width:200px here, but width: 120px on hover?  */
    height: 0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    left: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;  
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;  
    transition: all .3s ease; 
} 


.price:hover .detail {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="price strike">1.56
            <div class="detail">1.7% @ 1.6</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```